# How to search string from any position of ListView in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview on which i am setting custom arrayadapter with title and icon.
Title is s string which i am filtering using

```
     edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter = (GridAdapter) gridView.getAdapter();
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter = (GridAdapter) gridView.getAdapter();
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }
    });
```

But the i want to filter string from any index
For example i have a string like "Subcontractor HSSE Assessment and Selection Procedure"
and when i am searching from any index like "and Selection Procedure" then it wont works. But It is working for word at any index like when i am typing "Selection" but when i am putting space it wont work.

Please Help Me
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a strange subject for your post. As i understand you well everything works well. Only when the user types a space things go wrong. Please confirm.

Comment: yes thats the problem

Comment: Please show the filter code and adapt the subject of your post.

Comment: i am not writing any code for filer...getFilter() is method of ArrayAdapter itself

Comment: Ok. If the inbuild filter code does not work for you then better write your own.

Comment: but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Often i have seen such code on this site.  ArrayAdapters with their own getfilter method. I think a little searching will help you.

Comment: What you have to code is very simple. In principle you only have to loop through all items of the list of your adapter. Then compare every item with what the user typed in. Build a new list for the items that pass. Then do a notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: ur custom adapter extends BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter ?. Once post ur adapter code.

Comment: My adapter using ArrayAdapter bro

Comment: post ur custom adapter code

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom adapter

```
    private class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Categories> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, List<Categories> list) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icons);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
        holder.icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).getIcon());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        public TextView title;
        public ImageView icon;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override getFilter method in ur custom ArrayAdapter and implement the code:

```
class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Categories> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Categories> array, aListDump;

public GridAdapter(Context context, List<Categories> list) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.array = list;
    aListDump = list;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icons);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
    holder.icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).getIcon());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            array = (List<Categories>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        // getting results based on the search text view text
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            String seq = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<Categories> list = new ArrayList<Categories>();
            if (seq.trim().length() == 0 || seq == null) {
                results.count = aListDump.size();
                results.values = aListDump;
                list.addAll(aListDump);
            } else {
                for (Categories bean : aListDump) {
                    if (bean.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(seq.toLowerCase()))
                        list.add(bean);
                }
            }
            results.count = list.size();
            results.values = list;
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;
    public ImageView icon;

}
}
```

Comment: This code is working but the only problem is that notifyDataSetChanged(); is not working means arraylist not updating

Comment: I have edited.. local ArrayList and global arraylist having same name. So, nw I changed

Comment: and again problem is that when i type string from any position it wont be filter only word can filter..